# Move and Rotate UIButtons

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have one UIbutton. I want it to move from point A to point B. While going, that button have to do one full 360' rotation.

After some event, I want that UIButton to come back to its position, this time rotating in the reverse direction.

I wrote this code, but it didnt work. I'm seeing the button rotate in unexpected ways. What am I missing here?

To move:

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{

        CGAffineTransform rotate360AntiClockWise = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);

        CGRect initialFrame = button.frame;
        [button setTransform:rotate360AntiClockWise];
        [button setFrame:CGRectMake(initialFrame.origin.x - 140.0, initialFrame.origin.y, initialFrame.size.width, initialFrame.size.height)];

    }];
```

To comeback to the same position

```
   [UIView animateWithDuration:0.4 animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform rotate360ClockWise = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);

        [button setFrame:originalFrame]; //for movement 
        [button setTransform:rotate360ClockWise];

    }];

}
```

Comment: M_PI_2 and -M_PI_2 are the same angle. I think you need to do a 2-step rotation because CG picks the shortest rotation angle when deciding which way to rotate

Answer (score 0):

I can't try it at the moment, but if I remember correctly using the frame causes problems when applying transformations. Have you tried setting the center of the button?

```
[button setCenter:newCenter]
```

Where `newCenter` is a corresponding `CGPoint`.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do a rotation and a transform without messing up the Transformation matrix of the view is:

- place the button inside of a view (moveView) with the same frame-size with origin 0|0
- when you want to do a rotation, rotate the button
- when you want to move the button, translate the moveView

Answer (score 0):

Please do this in 3 steps

```
CGAffineTransform matOne = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(x_offset, y_offset);
CGAffineTransform matTwo = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
CGAffineTransform matResult = CGAffineTransformConcat(matOne, matTwo);
// Finally
[button setTransform:matResult];
```

I hope this helps you. Please make sure Concat has matOne as the first parameter.

Also this is a possible duplicate for another question:
[translation after rotation view using CGAffine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320491/translation-after-rotation-view-using-cgaffine)